# Is it possible to develope offline aaplication using gwt java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

Hi am working on project using gwt java on GAE. We developed one application using GWT JAVA GAE. This is web application I want to convert this application offline is it possible? any possible ways?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

GWT allows you to use all HTML5 features, so it's possible to build an offline app with GWT. There are a number of challenges that you will have to overcome - too many to discuss in an answer to your question. You may want to start with this excellent presentation:

[Easing offline web application development with GWT](http://www.slideshare.net/ltearno/easing-offline-web-application-development-with-gwt)